# Knowing parents from an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Considering this:

```
@article = Article.first(:joins => :category)
```

Does ActiveRecord provides a generique method which return a array of any belongs to class name?

For example:

```
@article.name.parents # => ["category"]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find all the "belongs_to" associations for your model, those of which are "parents" you can do this:

```
YourModel.reflections.select { |name, reflection| reflection.macro == :belongs_to }
```

Comment: Awesome idea! Many Thanks. I just add some other methods and it's okay: Article.reflections.select { |name, reflection| reflection.macro == :belongs_to }.collect { |table| table[0].to_s.classify }

Answer (score 0):

When you have a relation between two models, for example, an article having one category, you'll have a has_many relation in the category. And a belongs_to in the article.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles
end
```

Then you can, from either an article or a category, retrieve the related object.

```
article.category # => The category
category.articles # => The articles
```

There's no "parent". Each model has their own relations. If you need to retrive one model's relations, you must define it in order to have access to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A agree with you. But I would like to use a generic method to do so. If for example Article belongs to Category and Magazine, I would like to provide this:

@article.name.parents # => ["Category", "Magazine"]

But Article.parents method do not returns every belongs_to classes, and after testing some other methods such as:

@article.belongs_to

I get an error (because belongs_to require an argument) or an other information.  And after searching by trying this:

@article.class.methods.each { |method| begin @article.class.send(method) rescue true end }

I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible, cause what Rails is doing when having `belongs_to :something` inside some class, is a meta programming technique to add a method  `def something` inside that class and it doesn't really store those 'parent' classes.